# How to let authors only see website stats for their posts?

Tags: author, google-analytics, statistics

Is there a way to show each author website stats, just for the posts that they have published?

I run WP as a directory service (1 post each) and thought it would be handy for authors to be able to gauge how many hit/unique visitors/etc they are getting each day/week/month. I'm familiar with Google Analytics, and have played around with the google analytics dashboard plugin, but there doesn't seem to be any way to achieve what I am after. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> have played around with the google analytics dashboard plugin, but
>   there doesn't seem to be any way to achieve what I am after

There isn't, because to use that plugin in the manner you want, you need a different GA account for each author to track each author, and select that account in the plugin settings. Like you would have to do with any traditional stats plugin that uses JS to record page hits.

You could possibly make a template file for each author that includes the tracking code for each and then record and display hits that way, either by JS or PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You can set [custom variables](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingCustomVariables.html) in analytics that would contain the author name.  If you happen to use Yoast's [google analytics plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-analytics-for-wordpress/), one its options will let you do just that.

That would be the first step.  Collect data for a while (a month, maybe) and see if you're getting what you want.

After that, you'll probably have to write something (or have it built) that interacts with the [analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html) to fetch the required data and presents it all pretty-like for your users.

I don't have a more specific solution for you, but hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction.  I doubt you'll find a working, out of the box solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've familiar with custom variables and Yoast's plugin, but haven't found a way to only show each author their stats and not the whole site's stats.

Comment: I think you'll have to write something to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[SlimStat](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-slimstat/) is a plugin that will do just what you want with almost no config required. I worked perfect for me.  Now my authors can login and they see only what i want them to see and all the stats for their posts/content plus all the other great demographic type info.  I'm very lucky to have found it. so far it works great for me!